# 円グラフの凡例(文字)が重なってしまう

Tags: julia

julia langで円グラフを表示した際、以下のように凡例(国名の文字)が重なってしまいます。
これの解決策が調べても対処できなかったので質問しました。

[image: chart]

```
using Plots
gr()
x=["China", "India", "Uganda", "Ukraina", "Ostralia"]
data=[1.16, 0.056, 0.00529, 0.00189, 0.00156]
plot(x, data,seriestype=:pie,title="which country SSD export",legend=:best)
```

表示の仕方が上記の仕方でなくても良く、円の中に文字が入っていても良かったり、labelで一つに国の名前を掲載しても良いです。

ご指導のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`legend=:best`の部分を別のキーワードに変更するとどうでしょうか？

[How to change legends place with Plots, gr()?](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-change-legends-place-with-plots-gr/7294)

> Possible keywords are :right, :left, :top, :bottom, :inside, :best, :legend, :topright, :topleft, :bottomleft, :bottomright

[Attributes](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/)

> Symbol values: `:none`, `:best`, `:right`, `:left`, `:top`, `:bottom`, `:inside`, `:legend`, `:topright`, `:topleft`, `:bottomleft`, `:bottomright` (note: only some may be supported in each backend)

Comment: ありがとうございます、そのようにします！

Answer (score 1):

Windowsだと、`Plots` を使っていると駄目そうなので、`PyPlot` を直接使ってみました。
こんな感じでいけます。ウインドウの大きさにもよりますが。

```
using PyPlot
x=["China", "India", "Uganda", "Ukraina", "Ostralia"]
data=[1.16, 0.056, 0.00529, 0.00189, 0.00156]
pie(data)
legend(x, loc="lower right", fontsize="x-small")
title("which country SSD export")
```

[image: 表示結果]

Comment: ありがとうございます！ただPlots愛用家なので、なるべくPlots使いたい気もします。。

Comment: 開発元の Issues を探ってみて、無いようなら報告しておくと、いずれは対応されるかもしれません。　@cubickさんが紹介したように、ドキュメントには出来ると書いてあるわけですから。